# How to set matrix for Android FrameLayout?

Tags: android, matrix, xamarin.android

I'm trying to set matrix for Android FrameLayout/View like below code. But there is no changes in the view after applying matrix

```
FrameView.Matrix.Set(matrix);
```

The same matrix is working for image view

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

> But there is no changes in the view after applying matrix

The reason is that the matrix is not applied to the layout. There is no set method for FrameLayout to set the Matrix.

`FrameView.Matrix` is used to get the Matrix of the FrameView. And `Matrix.Set(matrix)` changes the value of the Matrix you get from FrameView but not apply to it.
 For example:

```
var frameLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.frameLayout1);
float[] f = new float[9];
float[] f2 = new float[9];
float[] f3 = new float[9];
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.PostRotate(10);
matrix.GetValues(f);
frameLayout.Matrix.GetValues(f2);
frameLayout.Matrix.Set(matrix);
frameLayout.Matrix.GetValues(f3);
```

After the set method called. The value of Matrix(f3) is still same as the original one(f2).

If you want to do some change to the layout, you could use a custom layout and do it in `OnDraw()`